# Trying to find the title of a fantasy book where the main character has living hair?

Tags: story-identification, magic

I'm trying to find the title of a fantasy book from the 90s.

This is what I remember seeing on the cover: she has wild white hair kind of changing into lighting and a shadow friend

**What I remember:**
Her hair is kept under a hood because it's living, she has a shadow no one sees that she talks to, she is a wizard or sorceress or something like that. There is a scene where she's drinking ale with the shadow...

Comment: Also, I think she is the daughter of a wizard in a previous book...

Comment: Obviously based on Medusa, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medusa Goggling 'Medusa' 'shadow' in books gets lots of hits.

Comment: thought it was Shambleau by C.L. Moore, given the living hair and that some book covers portrays white hair instead of red. howecer the other details don't fit. tried to search for it but found nothing yet that coresponds.